# ParseException when querying custom object: no results found for query. Code 101

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to create Android app with a Parse database of my alarms and everything looks nice when i create them however i cannot query them for some reason.

Alarm is being created by the same user. ACL for Alarm object is Public Read + Write. I tried to put only LOCAL_ID in query but still same result.

My code: here I'm creating my ParseObject

```
public static ParseObject createNewParseAlarm(Alarm alarm) {
    ParseObject parseAlarm = new ParseObject(ParseConstants.ALARM_CLASS);
    parseAlarm.put(ParseConstants.KEY_LOCAL_ID, alarm.getId());
    parseAlarm.put(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATED_BY, ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    parseAlarm = putValuesInAlarm(alarm, parseAlarm);

    return parseAlarm;
}
```

and here I'm querying it:

```
public static void updateParseAlarm(final Alarm alarm) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseConstants.ALARM_CLASS);
    query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATED_BY, ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_LOCAL_ID, alarm.getId());

    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){
                // Stuff happens when there is no error, but never actually get there yet as object is always null
                });
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "There was an error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it!

KEY_LOCAL_ID was a long type and got rounded when uploaded to Parse. Changed it to String and it works.